# Error executing CQL on layer other then demo layers

Tags: openlayers-2, geoserver, mapinfo, cql-filter

I have some sort of wierd problem as I was playing with CQL. CQL works well with given layer but when i try with layer loaded from mapinfo or some views then it does not work. As in the picture when I click the feature it shows the column called **NAME**  but when I query using  it (or other column) generates error like:

```
Property &apos;NAME&apos; could not be found in DISTRICT_BND
```

Why is the query not recognizing my column?

---

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am using sql server and found that the column name is case sensitive. May be this might be helpful for anyone that is having the same problem but I don't know why ?